# Changing the bound of summation

Tags: statistics

Would someone be able to clarify and explain how the following statement equal this:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} Xi$=$\sum_{i=1}^n Xi+X_{n+1}$

Comment: On the right hand side, you just pulled out the $X_{n+1}$ term from $\sum_i X_i$...

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}X_i=X_1+\cdots+X_n+X_{n+1}=(X_1+\cdots+X_n)+X_{n+1}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i+X_{n+1}$